# why does my table get under my box html?

Tags: html, css, css-position, html-table

Hello i'm new to html & css. I started with making a small box in wich i would like to display a table. But for some reason my table ends up under the box. the h4 somehow remains in the box. Please help.
box name = content2 and i made this in css like this.

```
#content2{
    margin: 30px 0;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
    clear: both;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div id="content2">
     <h4>Onze producten</h4>

    <table align="left">
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="../images/boy1.jpg" alt="Boy1" width="165" height="246" hspace="20" target="_blank" href="kleding.htm">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="../images/girl1.jpg" alt="Girl1" width="165" height="246" hspace="20" target="_blank" href="kleding.htm">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="../images/boy2.jpg" alt="Boy2" width="165" height="246" hspace="20" target="_blank" href="kleding.htm">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="../images/girl3.jpg" alt="Girl2" width="165" height="246" hspace="20" target="_blank" href="kleding.htm">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>600</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The align property is deprecated.  Margins should be used for alignment purposes for tables and block elements.

Answer (score 0):

try using overflow:hidden; in your css for #content2, post all your css for the table and it will be easier to figure out your problem

Comment: I didn't have any css for the table but the 'overflow:hidden;' did the trick. Thank you Sir !

Answer (score 0):

You have four td tags in the center tr tag and only three in the top and bottom tr tags. This will break your table. Either add additional td to top and bottom tr tags or use colspan="2" in one of the center td tags.

Comment: I totaly forgot about the td tags. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: While this is a valid observation, it doesn't answer the question.  This should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the default value for your div's overflow property is to allow things to render when they overflow like that, so you need to specify something else like overflow:hidden; or overflow:auto; to stop it from using the default behaviour.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

"visible: Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box."